# How to add a dot in scala enums values

Tags: scala, enums, scala-2.11

I have a following `enum`

```
object TestKeys extends Enumeration{

    type  TestKeys = Value
    val _id , uuid Status.Date= Value
}
```

I need to add the dot between `Status` and `Date` but Eclipse is not allowing me .I have done some research and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852253/how-can-i-get-enum-to-contain-a-dash). I found that there is a `DescriptionAttribute` in `c#` but its not working in Scala please help me how can i add dot in my enum values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use backticks around the name:

```
scala> object TestKeys extends Enumeration{
           type  TestKeys = Value
           val _id, `Status.Date` = Value
       }
defined object TestKeys
```

Note however that there are some unexpected side effects:

```
scala> TestKeys.withName("Status.Date")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value found for 'Status.Date'
  at scala.Enumeration.withName(Enumeration.scala:124)
  ... 33 elided

scala> TestKeys.withName("Status$u002EDate")
res7: TestKeys.Value = Status$u002EDate

scala> TestKeys.values
res8: TestKeys.ValueSet = TestKeys.ValueSet(_id, Status$u002EDate)
```

You can't have a `.` in a JavaIndentifier:

```
scala> Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(46)  // 46 is '.'
res16: Boolean = false
```

Comment: what is this $u002E ? can you please explain

Comment: @user3801239: `u002E` is the unicode value for a dot `.`. You can check this by running `'\u002E'.toChar` in a scala console. As for the `$`, it's used to interpolate a scala value inside a `String`.

Comment: You can fix `withName` using following construction:

    `val \`Status.Date\` = Value("Status.Date")`

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you need a way to write an identifier with dots in Scala. If that is the case, you can try something like:  `Status.Date`.

```
object TestKeys extends Enumeration{
    type  TestKeys = Value
    val _id , uuid, `Status.Date` = Value
}
```